# How to display all images of each category using Java?

Tags: java, sql

I have 2 table which look like this:

Table Images, contain link to the images

| CategoryId | imagesName | link |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | iphone.jpg | smartphone/apple/ |
| 1 | ipad.jpg | smartphone/apple/ |
| 1 | ipod.jpg | smartphone/apple/ |
| 2 | Nokia6A.jpg | smartphone/Nokia/ |
| 2 | Nokia6B.jpg | smartphone/Nokia/ |

Table category, contain the category and their description

| CategoryId | Title | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | Apple's smart devices |
| 2 | Nokia | Nokia smart devices |
| 3 | Samsung | Samsung smart devices |
| 4 | Kindle | Kindle's smart devices |

I have a homepage which need to display all the images sort by category, which they will look like:

```
 1 . Apple:
iphone.jpg
ipad.jpg
ipod.jpg
 2. Nokia
Nokia's images
3. Samsung
Samsung images
```

I haven't have any idea to write code to sort the images by `Category` like this. May anyone give me a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i< CategoryId.getLength(); i++){
  System.out.println(i+". " +  CategoryId.getTitle() + ":");// CategoryId.getTitle() don´t know your methods for that
  for(int ii = 0; i< CategoryId.getLength(); ii++){
    if(ii == i){
      System.out.println(CategoryId.get(ii).getimagesName());
    }
  }
}
```

First you iterate over all category Items like Apple, Nokia. Than you check if a the number equals the category Item you´re searching for. If this is the case, your print it out. Probably you have to modify the methods

> CategoryId.getTitle()

> CategoryId.getLength()

> CategoryId.get(ii).getimagesName()

what the last one should do: i presume that CategoryId is some kind of list or array. get the item on the place where you are looking for, an then get from that the name.